# When to repalce the Oil Filter on my Hyundai Accent 2006

Tags: hyundai, oil-change, oil-filter, accent, diesel-particulate-filter

I have a Hyundai Accent 2006 Diesel, it is time to change the oil on it, in the last oil change, i have changed: Oil Filter, the Oil(SWAG 10W40 ), Air filter, Diesel Wfilter, it has been 9000Kilimetre since the last oil change, so please can you suggest me what should i change in this comming oil change:

-type of oil
-do i have to change the filters(oil, diesel and air)? Are they still working just fine and i don't need to change them?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in the owner's manual. It will give you a service schedule on those items. If it doesn't, you can get the information from the Hyundai website.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to also change the oil filter when changing the oil in any car. The diesel filter is also recommended, depending on the quality of fuel you use, it might be ok or clogging up already (especially that filters are not expensive).